# sling configuration with postgreSQL

Tags: java, persistence, jackrabbit, jcr, sling

I am trying to integrate jackrabbit with PostgreSQL.While integrating I am getting following error.

```
HTTP ERROR 503

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Authentication Support service missing. Cannot authenticate request.
```

Comment: How have you tried to integrate Jackrabbit and PostgreSQL?

Comment: I was follow the steps given in the sling website https://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/jackrabbit-persistence.html

Comment: "Authentication Support service missing" is the typical error when the JCR repository cannot start. I would look at the sling/logs/error.log, and at the console output, for hints as to what went wrong.

Comment: 06.11.2013 10:13:34.330 *ERROR* [Repository Pinger] org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.PostgreSQLPersistenceManager failed to read bundle: deadbeef-face-babe-cafe-babecafebabe: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid namespace index: 3158064

Comment: 06.11.2013 10:13:34.330 *ERROR* [Repository Pinger] org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl failed to start Repository: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.ItemStateException: failed to read bundle: deadbeef-face-babe-cafe-babecafebabe: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid namespace index: 3158064 javax.jcr.RepositoryException: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.ItemStateException: failed to read bundle: deadbeef-face-babe-cafe-babecafebabe: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid namespace index: 3158064

Comment: 06.11.2013 10:13:34.331 *ERROR* [Repository Pinger] org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.server acquireRepository: Repository problem starting repository from file:/D:/sling%20Postgresql/sling/jackrabbit/repository.xml in D:\sling Postgresql\sling\jackrabbit (javax.jcr.RepositoryException: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.ItemStateException: failed to read bundle: deadbeef-face-babe-cafe-babecafebabe: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid namespace index: 3158064) javax.jcr.RepositoryException: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.ItemStateException:

Comment: Looks like JackRabbit can't connect to the repository, as it fails reading the root node. Can you post your repository XML in the question body? And also, can you validate that the given jdbc connectin details work from a standalone Java application running on the same machine?